# Geohash_grid aggregation in opensearch throws error

Tags: java, opensearch

I'm gettin this error when trying "geohash_grid" aggregation in java opensearch api. Seems opensearch doesn't have geohash_grid aggregation type, So what can be the analog, if that's the case?

```
"aggs": {
"filter_agg": {
  "filter": {
    "geo_bounding_box": {
      "ignore_unmapped": true,
      "location": {
        "top_left": {
          "lat": 90,
          "lon": -180
        },
        "bottom_right": {
          "lat": -90,
          "lon": 180
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "geo_centroid": {
            "field": "location"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

},

So when trying this query, I'm getting this error:

```
"Unknown aggregation type [geohash_grid]"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I resolved by downgrading the org.opensearch.client version to "2.2.1". Thanks to all, who tried to support me somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In Opensaerch you can use [geohex_grid](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/opensearch/geohexgrid-agg/) rather than geohash_grip.

```
GET national_parks/_search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "grouped": {
      "geohex_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://opensearch.org/docs/2.4/opensearch/geohexgrid-agg/

Comment: same error:
"Unknown aggregation type [geohex_grid]"

Comment: What is your Opensearch version?

Comment: that is 2.4.1, but i have tried this with higher version also.

Comment: Please share the full error with me

Comment: Caused by: org.opensearch.common.xcontent.NamedObjectNotFoundException: [14:26] unknown field [geohex_grid]